# Deleting multiple items based on global secondary index in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have an existing table which has two fields - primary key and a global secondary index:

```
----------------------------
primary key | attributeA(GSI)
----------------------------
1           | id1
2           | id1
3           | id2
4           | id2
5           | id1
```

Since having the attributeA as a global secondary index, can I delete all items by specifying a value for the global secondary index? i.e I want to delete all records with the attributeA being id1 - Is this possible in Dynamo?

Dynamo provides documentation about deleting the index itself, but not specifically if we can use the GSI to delete multiple items

Answer (score 37, accepted):

As of now, you cannot delete an item just by passing Non-key attributes or GSI keys.

The simplest way to do this is to Query GSI and get primaryKey(Hash key of the table) and Delete in next request.

You can refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9159431/2811189) if you want to do batchDeletion.

Hope that helps