# Does DynamoDB provides any API for deleting records based on GSI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

Is it possible to delete one or, more records from a DynamoDB table based on the Global Secondary Index?
I know that I can query the records first and then delete those records using the primary keys. But, I am looking for a single request logic which will save me RCU(s).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deleting multiple items based on global secondary index in DynamoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40163603/deleting-multiple-items-based-on-global-secondary-index-in-dynamodb)

Comment: I actually saw that answer. But, that was answered back in 2016. I was wondering if AWS provides any API of this kind in the newer DynamoDBv2 SDK because that might save a lot RCUs.