# How do I delete items from a DynamoDB table wherever an attribute is missing, regardless of key?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3, aws-cli

Is it possible to delete items from a DynamoDB table without specifying partition or sort keys? I have numerous entries in a table with different partition and sort keys and I want to delete all the items where a certain attribute does not exist.

AWS CLI or boto3/python solutions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

To delete large number of items from the table you need to query or scan first and then delete the items using [BatchWriteItem](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchWriteItem.html) or [DeleteItem](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/API_DeleteItem.html) operation.

Query and [BatchWriteItem](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchWriteItem.html) is better interms of performance and cost, so if this is a job that happens frequently, its better to add a global secondary index on the attribute you need to check for deletion. However you need to manage [BatchWriteItem](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchWriteItem.html) iteratively for large number of items since query will return paginated values.

Else you can do a scan and 
[DeleteItem](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/API_DeleteItem.html) iteratively.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9154264/what-is-the-recomended-way-to-delete-a-large-number-of-items-from-dynamodb) Stackoverflow question for more insight.

Answer (score 0):

It worth to try to use EMR Hive integration with DynamoDB. It allows you to write SQL queries against a DynamoDB. Hive supports DELETE statement and Amazon have implemented a [DynamoDB connector](https://github.com/awslabs/emr-dynamodb-connector/blob/master/README.md). I am not sure if this would integrate perfectly, but this worth a try. [Here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/EMRforDynamoDB.html) is how to work with DynamoDB using EMR Hive.

Another option is to use parallel scan. Just get all items from DynamoDB that match a filter expression, and delete each one of them. [Here is how](http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/dynamodb2_tut.html#parallel-scan) to do scans using boto client.

To speed up the process you can batch delete items using the [BatchWriteItem](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchWriteItem.html) method. [Here](http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/dynamodb2_tut.html#batch-writing) is how to do this in boto.

Notice that BatchWriteItem has following limitations:

> BatchWriteItem can write up to 16 MB of data, which can comprise as
>   many as 25 put or delete requests.

Keep in mind that scans **are expensive** when you are doing scans you consume RCU for all items **DynamoDB reads in your table** and not for items it returns. So you either need to read data slowly or provision very high RCU for a table.

It's ok to do this operation infrequently, but you can't do it as a part of a web-server request if you have a table of a decent size.