# Clear all data from a DynamoDB table without deleting it

Tags: node.js, typescript, amazon-dynamodb

How can I clear all items from a DynamoDb table without deleting and recreating the table? The table is created/defined using CloudFormation so I don't want to duplicate that concern in business code.

I'm using TypeScript/NodeJs.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9154264/what-is-the-recommended-way-to-delete-a-large-number-of-items-from-dynamodb) says to scan every item, chunk into blocks of 25, then delete each item using `BatchWrite`, however:

- It seems like I'm writing a lot of code do something that's presumably quite common.
- Scan returns items with their type, which I need to strip out, which involve a copy for every item, so again I'm writing a lot of code do something that's presumably quite common.

Is there a better way? Am I missing something?

Comment: There's no better way. I have been working with dynamo tables for years and I have never wanted for this functionality nor can I think of a legitimate use case.

Comment: OP points out their reasoning: "The table is created/defined using CloudFormation so I don't want to duplicate that concern in business code." Are you suggesting that this isn't a legitimate concern? If so, is there a better way to achieve it?

Answer (score 2):

Nope, those are your only two options:

1. delete and recreate the table
2. (Batch) Delete each item in the table

Why is this needed?

If this really is a "common need" for your application..
Have you considered more ephemeral storage, such as Elasticache?

What about DDB's ability to automatically expire and removed items via [TTL functionality](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/TTL.html)?